# Json vote up down script not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, json

This is my jquery code and this is working well. But when I display result inside the DIV. every time it is showing all values per result.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'vote.json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'vote_type='+vote+'&qid='+qid+'&aid='+aid,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $('.show_votes_likes').each(function (index, value){

            var data_votes = '';

            data_votes += '<span style="color:#66A835">'+data[index].likes+'</span>';
            data_votes += '<span class="up-votes-icon" onClick="give_vote(1)"></span>';
            data_votes += '<span class="down-votes-icon" onClick="give_vote(-1)"></span>';
            data_votes += '<span style="color:#CC5356">'+data[index].dislike+'</span>';

            $('.show_votes_likes').append(data_votes);
        });      

    }

});
```

This is vote.json file

```
[{"likes":"5","dislike":"0"},{"likes":"11","dislike":"-3"}]
```

Can you please tell me how can I show each separately.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in this line

```
        $('.show_votes_likes').append(data_votes);
```

you are appending to all div with ".show_votes_likes" class
instead that use this

```
        $(this).append(data_votes);
```

to reference to the actual div instead all

regards
Emiliano

Comment: Maybe? You're not sure?

Comment: "Maybe" ... is a kind of say, sorry for my expresions problems

Comment: @user3619039 if it works, can you upvote my answer please?